# Can I send json data by C socket ?

Tags: c, json, sockets

I want to use json for my networking protocol， and the json data is made up of some string and integer. Can I send the json by c socket ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Data is just data.  Sockets are a mechanism to communicating.  So you can send anything really.  So long as the receiving end is aware of what is being sent and understands what to do with it.

It's like a file, a file can store *anything* really.